# Setting navigationController?.navigationBar.isTranslucent = false in iOS 15 makes back button hit target too small and not work

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar, back-button

Super weird bug where my Navigation Controller back button wasn't working unless I tapped really right on it. On device it barely worked, on simulator I could click around and find the veeeery small hit target.

Here's what my nav bar settings look like in `viewWillAppear`

```
navigationController?.navigationBar.isTranslucent = false
navigationController?.navigationBar.tintColor = .white
navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = .black
navigationController?.navigationBar.barStyle = .black
```

Answer (score 3):

Turns out the problem line was this line inside my `viewWillAppear`:

```
navigationController?.navigationBar.isTranslucent = false // This line causes the hit target to be super small!
```

When I removed that line the hit target seemed to work fine (but of course my appearance was way off).

I found [this question](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/682420) which had a similar problem and solved my issue by re-working my entire appearanace to look like so:

```
let navAppearance = UINavigationBarAppearance()
navAppearance.configureWithOpaqueBackground()
navAppearance.backgroundColor = .black // previously my barTintColor
navAppearance.titleTextAttributes = [NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.white]
navigationController?.navigationBar.standardAppearance = navAppearance
navigationController?.navigationBar.scrollEdgeAppearance = navAppearance // yes, you need this

// Need this one legacy setting to change the buttons to be white
navigationController?.navigationBar.tintColor = .white
```